# A proverb / an expression to imply: "Enough is as good as a feast" or "Too much spoil, too little doesn't satisfy"

Tags: expressions, proverbs

Please imagine a situation that a person goes too far in doing something and in another task they son't put enough effort!

Or a cook who's making a food and salts a it too much, and the other food that he is preparing is saltless!

Or someone who respects you too much and the other time he / she disrespects you in public and so many other similar situations.

In my language there is a proverbial sentence which can be applicable to all these cases and ao many other scenarios in which a person is experiencing a very high and a very low stand confronting another person/situation! We say: (literal translation)

> - Not that salty, not this saltless.

In some translation pages the only sentences I found about this meaning are:

> - Enough is as good as a feast.
> - Too much spoil, too little doesn't satisfy.

But, I'm sure they are not how a native would convey the  same message through. So please let me know how shall I imply this meaning in a natural way?

Comment: Do not flag for moderator attention asking us to answer your questions. There is guidance in [this post on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/9161) for using flags properly, including a link to [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/273494). You can see that we have declined over 20 such flags in your [flagging history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to reference the story of [Goldilocks and the Three Bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears), which most English speakers know from childhood:

> Not too hot, not too cold.  Just right.

There's also a quote from Shakespeare's famous play "Hamlet" that is meant literally but can be used metaphorically as a warning against extremes:

> Neither a borrower nor a lender be.

"Enough is as good as a feast" only implies this in one direction, as a warning against greed or gluttony, but not against eating too little.

"Too much spoils; too little doesn't satisfy" is, I think, a translation of a Chinese proverb and not actually an English proverb.  This seems to relate more to the saying:

> Neither one thing nor the other

which implies the object is not really good for anything.  There is a similar Japanese proverb:

> *Obi ni mijikashi, tasuki ni nagashi* = "too short for a sash (to wrap around the waist of a kimino); too long for a cord (to tie up a kimono's sleeves)".

The English version might be:

> Too long for a belt; too short for a bootlace.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew; I read the story you linked above, but I couldn't get the relation between what I was looking for and the story! :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any web-page interpreting the proverbial sentence: "Too long for a belt; too short for a bootlace" @Andrew.

Comment: How shall I use the term "Goldilocks" here? I have to say: **"This is the same as the Goldilocks story; which you know that..."** or I have to say just: **"neigher too hot, nor too cold; just right"** and keep the name of the story for myself as a source of this sayng? Which variant is the one I have to know @Andrew?