# "Advantage" VS "Virtue"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the dictionary claims,

**Advantage** means:

> A good feature that makes something better than similar things.

And also, **virtue** means:

> **a.** The virtue of something is an advantage or benefit that it has, especially in comparison with something else. 
>   **b.** A virtue is a good quality or way of behaving.

Despite the wording style of the dictionaries, I don't see much difference between these two words in one of the following sentences, but it strikes me as if they cannot be swapped in two cases!  Please have a look on my examples and their relevant explanations:

> 1. Your **advantage / virtue** over him is your higher educational degree.

**Explanations:** here I think that "virtue" doesn't work here, while it can only refer to the "moral" aspects of someone.

> 2. One of the **advantages / virtues** of the electricity over gas is the lack of fumes.

**Explanations:** here the two nouns can be used interchangeably for me.

> 3. Patience is one of his **advantages / virtues**.

**Explanations:** I think these two words do not convey the same message here, while the stand-alone virtue alludes to the moral quality of someone that put they in a higher position comparing another person/people and "advantage" cannot indicate such a message by itself, unless I change it to "**moral** advantage".

Do you confirm my interpretation in the above-mentioned sentences? If not, then please let me know why?

Thank you.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208388/a-proverb-an-expression-to-imply-enough-is-as-good-as-a-feast-or-too-much#comment400907_208388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your assessment of the difference in usage between `advantage` and `virtue`.

If you use `virtue` alone, it indicates morality, such as your example `Patience is one of his virtues.`  Though for it to sound more natural, I would say something like `Patience is a virtue, and he has it in spades.`  (Having something "in spades" means you have a lot of it.)

If you use `virtues of` instead, your sentence would be crafted differently than using `advantages of`.  When comparing two things, you would want to use "advantages of".  Use "virtues of" when you're only discussing one thing.  Either of these would be correct usage: `One of the advantages of electricity over gas is...` or `One of the virtues of electricity is...`

Comment: Perfect answer @Mik. Thank you very much...